# Finding output resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis

I was trying to find output resistance of a circuit.

The book shows how to obtain Ro step by step. It says **Vπ** is equal to **-Vx**. I didn't get that point. My question is what is the relationship between **Vx** and **Vπ** in the below picture? Why?

[image]

Comment: Not going to try to decipher what's \$\pi\$ and \$x\$ in that picture.

Comment: V_pi appears across r_pi. The left side  of r_pi (plus V_pi) is at the same potential as the minus side of Vx. The right side of r_pi (minus V_pi) is at the same potential as the plus side of Vx. Therefore Vx=-V_pi.

Comment: okay. i see my mistake.

Comment: Re: R1||R2 see http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-07P0Cs7n2gs/UtqGs6OwL-I/AAAAAAAAf9Q/6CqFtXtGD2I/w1200-h630-p-nu/resistance+is+futile.png :o)

Comment: It is a test circuit for finding the output resistance for a common collector circuit - right?

Comment: It is a test circuit. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply simple KVL for the outermost loop,that has the resistor r-pi, voltage source v-x and the closed switch.